# Academic word meaning law-following with negative connotation/one dimensional

Tags: single-word-requests

The aim is to find a technical/academic jargon (likely multiple syllables) to describe the act of following the law to a fault. Even the phrase "to a fault" doesn't quite get at the valance I'm after, it's more about applying the law where it may technically be applicable but fails to account for crucial context. The idiom: "Aside from your husband, what did you think about the play, Mrs. Lincoln?" comes to mind.

Consider the sentence:

> As the theater burned, the gentleman threw a bouquet of flowers onto
> the stage for the actors. The gentleman is said to exhibit ________
> behavior.

I initially considered "irrational" or "abnormal" here, but his actions would be rational and normal in any other setting. So these two choices don't capture the emphasis I'm looking for.

Comment: It is not clear what sort of  emphasis you are looking for, anyway his   behavior could range from eccentric to irresponsible  I think.

Comment: @user66974 Right. Well, the emphasis is on the contrast between ignoring the crucial context and doing the formulaic thing that would otherwise be normal

Comment: To my mind "to a fault" and "one- dimensional" are not demonstrated by the example. It is therefore unclear what you are looking for.

Comment: Why necessarily resort to a single-word? It sounds like a pretty nuanced notion, and more words might work more magic than just one: Consider, perhaps, _"compulsive formality", "Indulging in norm-compliance..."_ or whatever else you fancy along such lines...

Comment: Is this ignorance (can't see the forest for the trees)? Or willful ignorance (to the letter)? Perhaps you could construct an actual academic-context sentence with a fill-in-the-blank.

Comment: A possible duplicate (if it wasn't on another site): https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56968/an-appropriate-term-for-an-overly-by-the-rules-person

Comment: What's wrong with _Algorithmic_? Haven't we seen enough stories about AIs acting like this? That's the meaning of the word, though Al-Khwarizmi might be surprised to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As the theater burned, the gentleman threw a bouquet of flowers onto
> the stage for the actors. The gentleman is said to exhibit
> **incongruous** behavior.

**Incongruous** (adj.)

> Disagreeing or inconsistent with the circumstances or requirements of
> the case, or with what is reasonable or becoming; unbecoming,
> unsuitable, inappropriate, absurd, out of place.
> OED

> Appearing strange or wrong within a particular situation
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/incongruous)

---

> Like many cognitive psychologists, Weems highlights the role of
> **incongruity** in jokes, how punchlines take us by surprise: "We laugh at what forces us to integrate incompatible goals or ideas that
> lead to confusion, doubt, and embarrassment." As an **example**, he offers
> the one-liner, "Other than that, how did you like the play, Mrs.
> Lincoln?"
> [William Costanzo; *When the World Laughs*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/When_the_World_Laughs/WDLNDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=incongruous%20%20enjoy%20the%20play%20mrs%20lincoln&pg=PA94&printsec=frontcover) (2020)

Comment: Although not an exact fit to the specification, this is a good approach to the answer and I do not understand why someone has casually voted it down without any explanation. I have therefore compensated. The words "crass" and "insensitive" come to mind both as possibilities for the answer and for the voting down.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps '[stringent](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/stringently)' could work:

> - rigorously binding or exacting; strict; severe:
>   *stringent laws.*
> - compelling, constraining, or urgent:
>   *stringent necessity.*

This can work in different contexts: when, e.g., someone strictly adheres to social convention—such as wanting to shake the hand of a surgeon in the middle of an operation—one could call that 'social stringency' or 'socially stringent'.
Your example sentence displays more of a 'customary stringency'.

An alternative to consider is '[rigid](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rigid)' ("*a rigid adherence to custom*").
More positive ones include '[unwavering](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unwavering)' and '[unyielding](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/unyielding)', as these emphasize a strength of will and resoluteness, rather than an inflexible stance in any given situation.